# WP Query - Search in title or author_name

Tags: wp-query, query, search

My need is to have a WPQuery that searches for posts which title is 'test' OR author_name is 'test'.

Here is the code I tried:

```
$search_query = get_search_query();

$args = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'title',
        'value' => $search_query,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'author_name',
        'value' => $search_query,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

I know that this code is meta_query style, but I'm trying to have OR in WP_Query

Answer (score -1):

*EDIT : Sorry just read that you need a 'OR' in your query. I will update anwser soon.*

According to your question, you can try this code.

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array(
    'name'                   => 'test',
    'author_name'            => 'test',
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // do something
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

**In the arguments, you should check if the parameters fits your needs :**

- `'name'` : Display post by slugs
- `'author_name'` : Display posts by author 'user_nicename'

If you need help building your query, you should definetly refer to theses links :

- Official documentation : https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
- Online generator : https://generatewp.com/wp_query/

Hope it help!